# Svg image is not properly showing using SVGKit

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uiimageview, svgkit

I have used SVGKit library to show svg images but the is some extra numbering in the images.

**Here is the actual image:**

[image]

**But the image shown in the imageView looks like this:**

[image]

As you can see in second image the numbers are showing on top and bottom in bunches are not part of the original image.

**How do I resolve this issue.I am using the svg image first time so I don't know the reason behind this.**

**Here is the code to show svg image from url:**

```
let svgURL = URL(string: imageUrl)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: svgURL)
let receivedIcon: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data)
                        self.svgImageView.image = receivedIcon.uiImage
```

Comment: Please add the code for svgView. It is likely that your sgView's frame size is not set the way you want it to be. You can also try scale aspect fill on both your webview and the svg. Try changing the background color of your views like webView and svgView to see their frame sizes.

Comment: I am setting the svg image in two ways the first is 3rd party library in which image size is perfectly fine but some image parts are missing(see image 2nd).But while using wkwebview the image shown is too small(Image 1st).

Comment: Try changing the color of your webView. It will show you how big the frame is. Does it cover the screen? If it doesn't cover your screen, then you need to change the frame of your webView.

Comment: Also the problem might be with the html file. In your third party library, your SVG is being resized. UIWebView might have trouble with sizing. Try and see how other people have loaded SVGs using UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You code is perfectly fine. If there is no issue with the SVG image, image will display surely. The issue is not with the WKWebView, issue is with the coding of SVG image. As we know that SVG is made of a html css code.., try to fix that css part.

Also please open your image link in browser and try to reduce the width height of the window, if css issue is there, surely your image will be displayed distorted.

Also follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814020/random-glitchy-rendering-of-svg-on-ios-wkwebview) too.