# Drop shadow not showing on sides on first load in Safari when using a border radius

Tags: css

I have an `img` inside a `picture` styled with rounded corners and a drop shadow:

```css
img {
  border-radius: 22%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.webp" />
  <source type="image/png" srcset="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.png" />
  <img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.png" />
</picture>
```

When first loaded in Safari (mobile or desktop) the shadow will only show on the corners, as shown below:

[image]

When the page is refreshed (or loaded in other browsers) the shadow is shown all around the image:

[image]

I had a JSFiddle that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/s0dy5jwa/17/show

I see even stranger results when using multiple elements. For example the following will be missing the drop shadow on the top of the first image and the bottom of the last image.

```html
<code>img</code> inside <code>picture</code>
<br/>
<picture>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.png" />
</picture>
<br/>
Just an <code>img</code> with PNG
<br/>
<img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.png" />
<br/>
Just an <code>img</code> with WebP
<br/>
<img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn.crispedge.com/c78b95.webp" />
```

[image]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s0dy5jwa/22/show

I've seen the same bug when using a mask to round the image so it seems to occur whenever the shape of the element changes.

Can this bug be worked around?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem. I have searched and found many different solutions. Safari seems to render filter:drop-shadow not correctly on elements using border-radius. Now I found out that in your case, the problem was not connected to this bug. `overflow:visible` is missing on your `img`-elements.

```
img {
  border-radius: 22%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s0dy5jwa/22/

But in my case, drop-shadow was still getting cut off by the parenting div. Strangely it rendered randomly correct or cut off on reload. For me what finally worked was this:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

And i had to group my images and using `drop-shadow` on the parent, like in this example: https://twitter.com/joshwcomeau/status/1407811337984647169

Here's a similar solution with code: [Why is filter(drop-shadow) causing my SVG to disappear in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705323/why-is-filterdrop-shadow-causing-my-svg-to-disappear-in-safari)

If it's still not rendering correctly, be sure to prefix it (`-webkit-filter:drop-shadow`) or try using ems instead of px.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but the shadow is still clipped. Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: I edited my initial answer. Your problem wasn't related to the safari bug.

Comment: I must be missing something, can you post a full example? Moving the `filter` to the container, adding `overflow: visible`, `appearance: none`, and `-webkit-filter` (https://jsfiddle.net/923ga6Ld/7/show) doesn't fix it. https://imgur.com/xUQk8ef

Comment: This problem is still present in Safari 17. I guess it is a bug and cannot be fixed with the proposed code above. This problem is difficult to replicate. Any redrawing of the page or part of it fixes the shadow display. It usually appears when you open the page for the first time in a newly created tab.

Answer (score 0):

give some padding.this have worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found adding:

transform: translateZ(0);

solved the flickering drop shadows I was having on iOS (Safari) during animations. The translate doesn't do anything visually but does move the rendering to the GPU.